# Microsoft Graph API returns mail message body as HTML

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, microsoft-graph-security

I want to read my email messages and transform them into json. I am using [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start) to query the office 365 mail box like this

```
GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(
            new DelegateAuthenticationProvider (
                (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                )
            );

var mailResults = await client.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request()
                                .OrderBy("receivedDateTime DESC")
                                .Select(m => new { m.Subject, m.ReceivedDateTime, m.From, m.Body})
                                .Top(100)
                                .GetAsync();
```

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial#displaying-the-results) tutorial to get to this stage. But my message body is returned as html instead of text. Is there a way I can specify the message.body to return text or even json instead of HTML?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't you have to set the HTTP request header:

> Prefer: outlook.body-content-type="text"

```
requestMessage.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type='text'");
```

As per the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations

Edit:

View the documentation, this is the client class code: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph/Requests/Generated/GraphServiceClient.cs

Here is an example from the link you're following:

```
private static GraphServiceClient GetClient(string accessToken, IHttpProvider provider = null)
{
        var delegateAuthProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
        {
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        });

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(delegateAuthProvider, provider ?? HttpProvider);

        return graphClient;
 }
```

Comment: Sure that looks like the option to use. But not sure how to use this in the GraphServiceClient ? Any clue?

Comment: I sure have this code but don't understand where/how do I specify the content-type for the body in this code.

Comment: You think I should specify something like this? requestMessage.Headers.Add("outlook.body-content-type", "text"); still doesnt work. Any other way to specify the header?

Comment: Hmm, can you try with the *Prefer:* and a few combinations, eg Prefer as the key and outlook.body-content-type='text' as the value.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!! you a legend mate! requestMessage.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type='text'"); worked!

Comment: NB: If your results span multiple pages, meaning you need to do `graphClient.NextPageRequest`, then you need to re-add the header using `graphClient.NextPageRequest.Header("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type='text'"); graphClient = await graphClient.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();` otherwise page 2 onwards will have HTML content bodies again.

Comment: While this option may achieve the goal, it lays down a problem for mocking of the graph client during creation of unit tests.  A better solution that supports mocking in unit testing is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183526/specifying-request-headers-using-c-sharp-office-graph-sdk-client

Answer (score 4):

With the GraphServiceClient, call `.Header("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type='text'")` as part of your request method chain:

```
var mailResults = await client.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Messages
                                .Request()
                                .Header("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type='text'")
                                .OrderBy("receivedDateTime DESC")
                                .Select(m => new { m.Subject, m.ReceivedDateTime, m.From, m.Body})
                                .Top(100)
                                .GetAsync();
```